# 'Undo' transformation of timeseries (i.o. to make it stationary and with no seasonal trend) to plot forecast

Tags: r, plot, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to re-create the paper "Box-Jenkins Seasonal Forecasting: Problem in a Case Study" (1973) in R. Now I'm almost done, but encounter a problem with the forecast.

In order to make the data stationary and to remove the seasonality, the difference of the sales data log (df) was taken twice.

```
# required lib
require(forecast);

# transform data
df=read.table("Sample.txt", header = TRUE)
df
ts<-ts(df, frequency=12, start=c(1965,1))
ts
ts_log10 <- log10(ts)
ts_log10
dd12zt <- diff(diff(ts_log10, 12))
dd12zt
```

(Sorry, I know there are more beautiful ways to write this.) After I check the most suitable ARIMA model, I forecasted the sales ​​for the next 12 months.

```
# Best fitting ARIMA
ARIMAfit <- auto.arima(dd12zt)
summary(ARIMAfit)

# Forecast
fcast <- forecast(ARIMAfit, h=12)
plot(fcast)
summary(fcast)
```

Of course, the values ​​of the forecast do not match those of the sample. My question is now how I best 'transform' the forecast data 'back' so I can plot it along with the original time-series?

**Data (Sample.txt):**
Sales
154
96
73
49
36
59
95
169
210
278
298
245
200
118
90
79
78
91
167
169
289
347
375
203
223
104
107
85
75
99
135
211
335
460
488
326
346
261
224
141
148
145
223
272
445
560
612
467
518
404
300
210
196
186
247
343
464
680
711
610
613
392
273
322
189
257
324
404
677
858
895
664
628
308
324
248
272

P.s. I'm sorry should I have posted something wrong. I'm still not very experienced with the stackoverflow habits. I am looking forward to tips and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auto.arima` function will handle the differencing and transformations for you. The following code should do what you want.

```
library(forecast)
y <- ts(c(154,96,73,49,36,59,95,169,210,278,298,245,200,118,90,79,78,91,167,169,289,347,375,203,223,104,107,85,75,99,135,211,335,460,488,326,346,261,224,141,148,145,223,272,445,560,612,467,518,404,300,210,196,186,247,343,464,680,711,610,613,392,273,322,189,257,324,404,677,858,895,664,628,308,324,248,272),
         frequency=12, start=c(1965,1))
fit <- auto.arima(y, lambda=0, d=1, D=1)
fcast <- forecast(fit)
plot(fcast)
```

However, I think a log transformation is too strong. I'd use something like `lambda=0.4`. Also, you don't really need the first difference, the seasonal difference is sufficient. If you just let `auto.arima` handle it for you, the results are pretty good:

```
fit <- auto.arima(y, lambda=0.4)
fcast <- forecast(fit)
plot(fcast)
```

[image]